# flutter stripe payment error No payment sheet has been initialized yet

Tags: android, flutter, dart, stripe-payments, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to implement the stripe payment method in Flutter.

But it gives an **issue** saying:

> flutter: Exception/DISPLAYPAYMENTSHEET==> StripeException(error:
> LocalizedErrorMessage(code: FailureCode.Failed, localizedMessage: No
> payment sheet has been initialized yet, message: No payment sheet has
> been initialized yet, stripeErrorCode: null, declineCode: null, type:
> null)) #0      MethodChannelStripe._parsePaymentSheetResult
> (package:stripe_platform_interface/src/method_channel_stripe.dart:310:11)
> #1      MethodChannelStripe.presentPaymentSheet (package:stripe_platform_interface/src/method_channel_stripe.dart:246:14)
>  #2      Stripe.presentPaymentSheet
> (package:flutter_stripe/src/stripe.dart:367:12)  #3      FutureExtensions.onError.
> (dart:async/future.dart:1049:15)

I checked all my build settings on Android as well as iOS setting everything is fine.

Here is **my code** for the stripe payment method:

```
Future<void> makePayment() async {
  try {
    paymentIntentData = await createPaymentIntent('20', 'USD');
    await Stripe.instance
        .initPaymentSheet(
            paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
          paymentIntentClientSecret:
              paymentIntentData != null ? ['client_secret'].join('') : null,
          style: ThemeMode.light,
          merchantDisplayName: 'John',
        ))
        .then((value) {});

   await displayPaymentSheet();
  } catch (e) {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
}

displayPaymentSheet() async {
  try {
    await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet().then((newValue) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('payment intent${paymentIntentData!['id']}');
      }
      print('payment intent${paymentIntentData!['client_secret']}');
      print('payment intent${paymentIntentData!['amount']}');
      print('payment intent$paymentIntentData');
      //orderPlaceApi(paymentIntentData!['id'].toString());
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
          content: Text("Congratulation you have buy 20 Credits")));

      paymentIntentData = null;
    }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('Exception/DISPLAYPAYMENTSHEET==> $error $stackTrace');
      }
    });
  } on StripeException catch (e) {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print('Exception/DISPLAYPAYMENTSHEET==> $e');
    }
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => const AlertDialog(
              content: Text("Cancelled "),
            ));
  } catch (e) {
    print('$e');
  }
}

createPaymentIntent(String amount, String currency) async {
  try {
    Map<String, dynamic> body = {
      'amount': calculateAmount(amount),
      'currency': currency,
      'payment_method_types[]': 'card'
    };
    var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents'),
        body: body,
        headers: {
          'Authorization':
              'Bearer sk_test_key,
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        });

    return jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
  }
}

calculateAmount(String amount) {
  final price = int.parse(amount) * 100;
  return price.toString();
}
```

Here is my **main file**:

```
    void main() async {

      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      Stripe.publishableKey = 'pk_test_';
      Stripe.merchantIdentifier = 'any string works';
      await Stripe.instance.applySettings();


      runApp(const MyApp());
    }
```

It did not work on real devices both in Android and iOS. I checked all my build settings on Android as well as iOS setting. Everything looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing this in the wrong order. You need to follow this [guide](https://docs.page/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/sheet#3-integrate-the-payment-sheet-client-side).

First `await` the creation of the PaymentIntent, then `await` the `initPaymentSheet` where you pass the secret from the PaymentIntent creation method and then `presentPaymentSheet`.

Comment: I am doing precisely like that 1st await payment intent then initPaymentSheet then present paymentseet if you check my code

Comment: after editing your question, I think the problem now is with `paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntentData != null ? ['client_secret'].join('') : null` which should be replaced by `paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntentData!['client_secret']`